# aws-cli (powershell) import-image Missing required parameter disk-images

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm trying to import a vhd to s3 using the following command:

```
aws ec2 import-image --description "my image" --platform "windows"
```

The error generated is the following:

> A client error (InvalidParameter) occurred when calling the ImportImage operation: Missing required parameter (disk-images)

The documentation doesn't mention disk-images. Is there an example of how this command should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example below indicates that you are missing a pointer to .json (configuration file):  [Example: import-image to create a new import image task.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ImportVMImportImage.html)

> > import-image --description "Windows 2008 OVA" --disk-containers file://containers.json

[CLI Options for 'import-image' command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/import-image.html)